# Rating decreased suddenly without reason, FIDE rating displayed wrongly in the website can anyone have such Problems

Tags: fide, rating, tournament, evaluation, calculation

My son's rating opened when he played international match during August 2023. The rating was displayed in FIDE website on the last date of August, and it was 1156.

Later on September he played another international tournament and there was no change in rating. That was also displayed in FIDE website on last date of September as 1156.

It was the same till October 7th and suddenly on 8th October his rating is displayed as 1031 in the FIDE website. Do anyone can help to fix this issue?

Comment: This website has no connection to FIDE so the answer is no. We have no clue why. If you share your son's FIDE ID or name someone might be able to look at the data on the FIDE website and work out what is going on

Comment: Might it be that the results of his last tournament were calculated just now? For FIDE to calculate ratings the organizer of the tournament has to send them the results and this process can - depending on the tournament organizer - take some time. It is not unheard of that a month delay happens.